# How to prevent stuff from being exported

Tags: org-mode

I want some stuff to be visible in the editor, but not in the export (`C-c C-e`). Some stuff includes headlines. I tried this:

```
#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME: ~/Documents/Outbox/hide
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
#+STARTUP: indent
#+STARTUP: hideblocks
* Foo
  :DRAWER:
  - `M-x org-insert-drawer` for stuff to be hidden.
  - Unfortunately, you can't put a subtree in it, AFAIK
  - Besides, this does get exported.
  - What is meant by hidden, then?
  :END:

#+BEGIN_HIDE
You can't hide, or can you?
#+END_HIDE
```

And that's what I get from `C-c C-e l l`:

```
\section{Foo}
\label{sec:org2b52cc8}
\begin{itemize}
\item `M-x org-insert-drawer` for stuff to be hidden.
\item Unfortunately, you can't put a subtree in it, AFAIK
\item Besides, this does get exported.
\item What is meant by hidden, then?
\end{itemize}

\begin{HIDE}
You can't hide, or can you?
\end{HIDE}
\end{document}
```

Manual:

[Drawers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Drawers.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I prevent export of an org subtree?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53418/can-i-prevent-export-of-an-org-subtree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `noexport` tag to headlines, in order to avoid exporting them:

```
* This section is not going to be exported                              :noexport:
  The whole section (and all its subsections) is NOT going to be exported.
```

See the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-Settings) and look for `EXCLUDE_TAGS`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add `#+OPTIONS: d:nil` in the preamble to prevent your drawer to be exported (and even all drawers). You can also customize (locally, or in your .emacs) the variable `org-export-with-drawers`.
2. It is unclear to me what is your `#+BEGIN_HIDE` environment, and what you intend to write in it. But both your drawer and "hide" environment could be simply replaced by headlines with the `:noexport` tag. I would definitely go for that solution in both cases.

Comment: or `#+BEGIN_SRC text :exports none` and to hide a specific drawer see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30297651/1365754